# How to add suffix numbers at end of XML tags?

Tags: xml, powershell

I am parsing an XML file in PowerShell, but am running into an issue for which I can't figure out a solution.

Below are the contents of the xml file:

```
<hostcount>2</hostcount>

<hostconfig>
<hostname1>host1.fqdn.local</hostname1>
<hostroot1>root</hostroot1>
<hostpassword1>p@ssw0rd</hostpassword1>

<hostname2>host2.fqdn.local</hostname2>
<hostroot2>root</hostroot2>
<hostpassword2>p@ssw0rd</hostpassword2>
</hostconfig>
```

I want to be able to pull this into a variable in PowerShell. I am parsing the XML file, but when I try to copy the XML into a variable I get an error.

Below is a snippet of my powershell script:

```
$i = 1

$host1 = $xml.hostconfig.hostname$i
```

Now, I know the above is wrong, but how do I get the `$i` to stick in there? Ideally I want to loop through the XML and pick up all the host info.

Comment: I think i got it - instead of doing this i simply used a foreach in pshell and did a foreach($i in $xml.element){ $array += $i.name} and it worked well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

According to me, your XML file is not well formed. Can't you try the following:

```psh
$xml = @"
<Computers>
  <hostcount>2</hostcount>

  <hostconfig>
   <host>
     <hostname>host1.fqdn.local</hostname>
     <hostroot>root2</hostroot>
     <hostpassword>p@ssw0rd2</hostpassword>
   </host>

   <host>
     <hostname>host2.fqdn.local</hostname>
     <hostroot>root2</hostroot>
     <hostpassword>p@ssw0rd2</hostpassword>
   </host>

  </hostconfig>
</Computers>
"@

$a = [XML]$xml
$hostcount1 = $a.Computers.hostcount
$hostcount2 = $a.Computers.hostconfig.ChildNodes.count
$host1 = $a.Computers.hostconfig.ChildNodes[0].hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you follow [@JPBlanc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075434/1630171)'s suggestion. Specifying object details as child nodes

```xml
<host>
  <hostname>host1.fqdn.local</hostname>
  <hostroot>root2</hostroot>
  <hostpassword>p@ssw0rd2</hostpassword>
</host>
<host>
  <hostname>host2.fqdn.local</hostname>
  <hostroot>root2</hostroot>
  <hostpassword>p@ssw0rd2</hostpassword>
</host>
```

or as attributes

```xml
<host hostname='host1.fqdn.local'
  hostroot='root2'
  hostpassword='p@ssw0rd2' />
<host hostname='host2.fqdn.local'
  hostroot='root2'
  hostpassword='p@ssw0rd2' />
```

of a parent node that represents the object class makes a lot more sense than numbering each node to attribute it to a particular object.

However, if for some reason you are not at liberty to change the XML format, you could access numbered nodes like this:

```psh
$i = 1
$xml.hostconfig."hostname$i"
```